# Understanding OFFSET function

Tags: microsoft-excel

OFFSET(cell_reference, number of rows to offset by, number of columns to offset by)

Based on the above, I try this:

=OFFSET(reference,5,5)

[image]

[image]

My expectation was that the whole table (reference) will be shifted to (offset by) 5 rows and 5 columns. But getting 0 as output. It will help understand the exact purpose of OFFSET and how it is used.

Comment: Have a look at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/offset-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66 or search for "Excel offset worksheet function". Offset doesn't move things, instead it creates a reference (typically a range of cells) which is defined by its offset from another reference.

Comment: One thing people often struggle to wrap their heads around in Excel is that a formula in one cell cannot modify the contents of another cell¹. I.e. you **cannot** write a formula in say cell C1 like `=IF(A1 > B1, copy A1 to D1, copy B1 to D1)` because you are asking cell C1 to modify cell D1. For the same reason you cannot expect OFFSET (or any other function) in cell F7 in your example to move or copy the table anywhere, except reference value(s) from the table and display or calculate with them in F7 (or spill over into F7's adjacent cells¹).

Comment: ¹ There are a few exceptions to the rule: array formula can spill over into adjacent cells and VBA macro code or UDFs can be tricked or forced to modify cells beyond their own cell. The latter can create circular formula or infinite calculation loops. Not advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OFFSET` is not for moving data, but finding something relative to something else.

Your formula is saying "return the data that is 5 rows down and 5 columns to the right of reference". That cell is empty, so it returns zero.

If you want to put the data from the named range somewhere else, you just type `=reference`.